# Creating subitems of a model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a ToDoList application built via angular just for a bit of practice.

What i've got working:

- Can Add/Remove ToDos
- Get SubItem panel to show

What I haven't got working:

- Struggling how to add a sub item. This is what i've tried:

  ```
  <head>
  <title>ToDo</title>
  <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/Controllers/ToDoController.js"></script>
   </head>
  ```

  ```
      <form>
          <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="toDoItem" placeholder="Enter your To-Do" ng-model="toDo"/>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addToDo()">Add To Do</button>
              </span>
          </div>
      </form>
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-repeat="x in toDoArray track by $index">
              <p>{{x}}</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeToDo($index)">Remove To Do</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="showSubItem()">SubItem</button>
              <div id="subItemPanel" class="panel panel-default" style="margin-top: 5px;" hidden>
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSubItem($index)" type="button">Go!</button>
                      </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <li class="list-group-item" style="margin-top: 5px;" ng-repeat="subItem in x ">
                  <p>{{subItem}}</p>
              </li>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
  <script>

   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

   app.controller('myCtrl',
      function($scope) {
          $scope.toDo = "";
          $scope.toDo.subItem = [];
          $scope.toDoSubItem = "";


          $scope.clicked = false;
          $scope.toDoArray = [];

          $scope.showSubItem = function(toDoIndex) {
              $("#subItemPanel").show();
          }

          $scope.addSubItem = function(toDoIndex) {
              $scope.toDoArray[toDoIndex].subItem.push($scope.toDoSubItem);
          }

          $scope.removeToDo = function (toDoItem) {
              $scope.toDoArray.splice(toDoItem, 1);
          }

          $scope.addToDo = function () {
              $scope.clicked = true;
              $scope.toDoArray.push($scope.toDo);
          }
      });
  </script>
  ```

I'm getting an issue with pushing to the subItem property, I kind of expected this but have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle ?

Comment: @Korte ive tired but the fiddle doesnt work like it does on my pc

Comment: Here is the working code: https://plnkr.co/edit/CoW0YFRnnxeSS4KaFb4v?p=preview. Hope this helps.